# What is the difference between passing returning type in selector vs inferring it?

Tags: c#

Are there any advantages to doing this:

```
dr.Select<PurchaseRequestFile>(CreatePurchaseRequestFileBindProps).FirstOrDefault();
```

instead of (avoid passing returning type):

```
dr.Select(CreatePurchaseRequestFileBindProps).FirstOrDefault();
```

For function:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Select<T>(this SqlDataReader dr, Func<SqlDataReader, T> selector)
{
    if (dr == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("dr");
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        yield return selector(dr);
    }
}
```

thanks,

Comment: Aside from the obvious readability differences, there is no functional difference.

Comment: One is shorter.  They both compile to the exact same code, but in one the compiler itself is determining types for you.

Comment: Assuming the `T` that the compiler infers is the one you would otherwise specify directly, they're exactly the same. But there are cases when they *won't* be the same type... at which point, you need to specify the type argument directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of `CreatePurchaseRequestFileBindProps` taking `PurchaseRequestFile` there will be no difference: the type of `T` inside the generic method would be the same. Apart from the code length, everything else would compile and run the same.

Note that there are situations when you could force a different type from what would otherwise be inferred. For example, you could supply a subclass of `PurchaseRequestFile` to give type argument `T` a different, but valid, value.

Here is a short example where inferred and explicit specifications may diverge:

```
static T Demo<T>(Func<int,T> a) {
    var res = a(42);
    Console.WriteLine("Returning {0} as {1}", res, typeof(T).FullName);
    return res;
}

private static string Foo(int n) {
    return n.ToString();
}

public static void Main() {
    Demo(Foo);
    Demo<object>(Foo);
}
```

This produces the following output ([demo](https://ideone.com/wZqbps)):

```
Returning 42 as System.String
Returning 42 as System.Object
```